# AJAX form won't post form values, when inside a php while loop

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I'm having a problem with my code. the html form wont post the values with AJAX, when pressing the "indsend feedback" button. The jquery code works fine when only including a button with a value inside the form, but when i try to include multiple elements, it no longer works and starts posting an empty array.

The code works fine, when used standalone outside the project.

HTML CODE HERE FOR THE FORM and WHILE LOOP.

```
        <tbody>
        <?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM psv2_orders_lines, psv2_orders WHERE psv2_orders_lines.order_id = '$orderid' AND psv2_orders.id = '$orderid'";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbCon));
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                <!-- // Der laves en echo, hvor der udskrives ordrebilledernes destinationer.. -->
                <span class='zoom ex2'>
                    <img src="img/ordrer/<?php echo $orderid,"-", $rowcompany['company'], " ", $row['product'],"/", $row['style_1'],"1",".jpg";?>"
                        alt="..." class="img-fluid imgsize">
                </span>
                <span class='zoom ex2'>
                    <img src="img/ordrer/<?php echo $orderid,"-", $rowcompany['company'], " ", $row['product'],"/", $row['style_1'],"2",".jpg";?>"
                        alt="..." class="img-fluid imgsize">
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['line'];?></td>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <h5>Style 1</h5>
                        <?php echo $row['style_1'];?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <h5>Style 2</h5>
                        <?php echo $row['style_2']; ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <h5>Style 3</h5>
                        <?php echo $row['style_3']; ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <h5>Style 4</h5>
                        <?php echo $row['style_4']; ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <form method="post" action="feedback.php" class="feedbackknap">
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Skriv problemet her..."
                                name="orderrejectcomment"></textarea>                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" name="style1" value="hej" class="btn btn-dark">Indsend
                        feedback</button>
                </td>
                </form>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>

    </tbody>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.feedbackknap').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
        data[name] = value; 
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

return false;
});});
```

PHP action folder:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, will try to fix it.

Comment: <?php
function mysqli_entities_fix_string($dbCon, $string) {
 return htmlentities(mysqli_fix_string($dbCon, $string));
}

function mysqli_fix_string($dbCon, $string) {
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
 return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $string);
}
?> wouldnt tihs function prevent corrupt data?

Comment: No, that function would corrupt the data. Don't use such functions.

Comment: So in theory i should delete all or die statements in my code? And find a way to secure my inputs, so that i dont recieve corrupt data?

Comment: Yes. Enable proper error reporting and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use `serializeArray()` to serialize in array your entire form like this.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's posting the textarea value now, but seems it still wont post the value from the button. Thank you for your time!

Comment: try to change it to an input type="submit" **EDIT** do not forget  `preventDefault` to prevent the real submit !

Comment: Seems like the $(this).serializeArray() makes the button value invalid? Have you experienced this before?

Comment: look at my previous comment, i think button is not a real form component.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now! It all works, made an invisible input element, with a value in it. It's posting the values correctly now.
Have a nice day!!